# Proxy all requests for subdomain to an ip via htaccess/apache

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, .htaccess, ip, subdomain

Let's say I have the following subdomain with its own document root etc:

```
monad2.mysite.com
```

I want that all requests are proxied to an IP (for instance `193.159.3.129`) but they must pass through the server at `mysite.com` (assuming `monad2` is on this same server).

I have the following (htaccess) config which works up to the subdomain, but fails to proxy any other request...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://193.159.3.129/$1 [P]
```

My problem is that while it does work for `http://monad2.mysite.com/a.php` (url remains the same), it doesn't work with requests like `http://monad2.mysite.com/a/b` (url is converted to `http://193.159.3.129/a/b`). Note that the latter address shows a directory listing of the proxied server, which is correct, except that the subdomain changed to an ip.

Also, I presume this system will definitely not work for HTTPS requests, correct?

**Edit:** After some more troubleshooting, I've found exactly when the problem is being caused.
Whenever I try to access a directory without the final slash, the proxy fails, and I end up with an IP. Some example:

```
Original                        | Result
--------------------------------+--------------------------------
http://monad2.mysite.com        | http://monad2.mysite.com
http://monad2.mysite.com/a/     | http://monad2.mysite.com/a/
http://monad2.mysite.com/a      | http://193.159.3.129/a/           <- !
http://monad2.mysite.com/a.php  | http://monad2.mysite.com/a.php
```

Comment: Do you have access to the actual Apache configuration, or just an htaccess file?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I have root access, but I kind of preferred using htaccess. I'm perfectly fine with an alternative solution though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `ProxyPassReverse` - it catches `Location` fields in response headers and alters them so that the client will continue talking to the proxy, instead of the backend server.

`ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` cannot be in an `.htaccess` file - so replace your current rewrite rule with this, which should go inside your `<VirtualHost>` block for the subdomain:

```
ProxyPass / http://193.159.3.129/
ProxyPassReverse / http://193.159.3.129/
```

As an aside: do not use `.htaccess` when you can avoid it.  Review the [Apache documentation on the matter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when).

> In general, you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have access to the main server configuration file.

Comment: Ah, tried that one but didn't work, probably because I tried it in the .htaccess. Regarding the 'not to use htaccess' part, though it is understandable, everyone knows that it is impractical. `.htaccess` are just so convenient. Heck, even I that know my own server better than anyone else will take me several minutes to find the right apache config file. That said, thanks a lot for your help...I'll reply soon when I get it working (or break everything up!) **;)**

Comment: Sounds like you need to do a better job of naming and/or organizing your configs.

Comment: @ScottPack Tell that to the guys creating CPanel :(

Comment: Hmm, I noticed cookies fail to work. Any idea why?

Comment: OK, I've fixed it with this PHP code: `if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == '193.159.3.129')$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'monad2.mysite.com';` any idea why Apache didn't proxy this value by itself?

Comment: Add `ProxyPreserveHost On` to your config to have the host header sent to the PHP server, or use `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` to alter the cookie domain in the response header.